# Error running sharepoint project in Azure pipeline

Tags: sharepoint, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sharepoint-online

I am receiving the below error when i try to run my Sharepoint console app in the Azure pipeline. Can someone help me to understand what I am missing here?  The solution builds successfully on my VS solution locally.

***The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)***

Comment: Hi, please check whether my answer below can help you. If not, could you try using [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) and tell us whether the error still occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some troubleshooting advice:

1. If you add references to nuget packages, please make sure that you have restored nuget packages correctly and make sure that the path point to the correct packages folder. You can refer to [this blog](https://www.codeart.dk/blog/2020/3/packages-restored-but-your-project-is-still-missing-references/).
2. If you directly add references by dll, you need to push your dlls to your repository. Please make sure the `.csproj` uses the relative paths rather than full paths.
3. Make sure that you are using target framework corresponding to your SharePoint version.